# How to make ImageView on RecyclerView to have a dimension set while Glide is loading the image?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-glide

I have some problem regarding my ImageView inside my `RecyclerView`. I am creating a comics viewer and I load very long images. I sliced my images to 8 part so my `ImageView` can handle them. The problem is when loading the image on `RecyclerView`.

I am using `Glide` and when `Glide` is loading the segmented parts, there is quite noticeable delay. Which is preferable due to image caching and it works very well but it left an undesirable effect. I can't show an actual image since it is happening very fast but I can represent it using `ASCII`:

For example here is my `RecyclerView` on startup:

```
---------------Segment1
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
---------------Segment2
---------------Segment3
---------------Segment4
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
#.........................
```

As you can notice here, Glide is not yet finished loading Segment2 and Segment3 and in effect, Shows Segment1 and Segment4 stitched together. All of sudden Segment2 and Segment3 popped out of existence which isn't very nice.

Even if I placed this on a `ScrollView` and dynamically add `ImageView` into it, it would be the same effect. I cannot assign constant px/dip on width and height on an `ImageView` for obvious reasons as I need to handle multiple screen sizes.

My `ImageView` setup looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_comic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what I am doing when I bind to this `ImageView`:

```
private void bindSegment(ComicViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    File file = mSegments.get(position);
    Point imageSize = Constants.getImageSize(file);
    Point screenSize = Constants.getScreenSize(mContext);

    ImageView imageView = holder.mImageViewComic;

    Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
        .load(file.getAbsolutePath())
        .override(imageSize.x , imageSize.y)
        .crossFade(0)
        .into(imageView);
}
```

If I assign a constant pixel width/height based on `ImageView` via `getLayoutParams()`, I can get it to work on one phone and not the other. I cannot hardcode `ImageView` size this way. `Glide.override` doesn't seem to work as I expected. I need my `ImageView` to know its current dimension base on the size of the image being loaded so it fill in the gap between loaded segments and not popping out of existence.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support provided by Glide library for this issue. I had tried many times. However, finally I on my own derived a solution. For loading the image you must be sending the URL of the image and some more metadata.

The solution is, with this metadata you need to send the dimensions(height and width) of the image which is going to be loaded in your imageview.

You will get these dimensions before your image is loaded in the imageview. Now, you need to scale the height and width of your imageview with these dimensions and apply a placeholder for this.

Finally when your image will be loaded it will take the place of your placeholder.

I am supposing you are going to set the width of your imageview = width of your screen

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    int width = 0, height = 0;

metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
```

height = metrics.heightPixels;
        width = metrics.widthPixels;

Now,

```
int heightOfImage = 0;
int widthOfImage = 0;

float scalingRatio = ((Float.parseFloat(heightOfImage) / Float.parseFloat(widthOfImage));

 viewHolder.imageLoadingLayout.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(scalingRatio*width );  //imageLoadingLayout is your placeholder
```

Finally,

```
    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(imageURL)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    viewHolder.imageLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    return false;
                }
            })
            .crossFade()
            .override(1700, 1700)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView);

}
```

Image Layout

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 />
```

Comment: Jesus christ this worked. But my scaled images are a bit elongated but never the less it worked.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> newPostHolder.height = DeviceHight;
>  int heightOfImage = data.getInt("image_height");
>                     if (heightOfImage > ((newPostHolder.height / 100) * 80) || heightOfImage == newPostHolder.height) {
>                         heightOfImage = ((newPostHolder.height / 100) * 69);
>                     }
>
>                     newPostHolder.one_imageview.getLayoutParams().height = heightOfImage;
> ```